# How to update my global prices and delete website prices?

Tags: magmi, scope

In Magento I configured global prices - 1 price for all websites/stores/languages.
Unfortunately, Magmi imported prices in the website tables (in case there is anything like a website table).
So now I've got global prices if I manually enter a product and I if use Magmi to import a product into two different languages, I've got website scope prices.

Is it somehow possible to delete the website prices and tell Magento (or does it do it by itself) to use the global prices?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would do what Sanders said and change your price scope to "**Global**". Then, if for whatever reason you have website prices that persists, I would run the following query, which will return all of the non global prices saved on your database.

```
SELECT d.entity_id AS product_id,d.value AS price
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal AS d
    INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS a
        ON d.`attribute_id` = a.`attribute_id`
WHERE a.`attribute_code` = 'price'
    AND d.store_id != 0
```

First examine these records, if any. If you're seeing website prices, this query should return some results. If you remove these records, all prices will fall back to the global price (`store_id = 0`). Proceed with caution and always test it on a dev environment first!

Comment: Don't do this on a production environment and always make a backup first. ;)

Comment: Edited slightly :)

Comment: A bit scary but after backups and testing around it seems as if it's working fine - thank you @musicliftsme for this solution.

I used:
`code`
 DELETE d.*
 FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal AS d
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS a ON d.`attribute_id` = a.`attribute_id`
 WHERE a.`attribute_code` = 'price'
 AND d.store_id !=0

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `Catalog Price Scope` to **Global** under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Price` it should ignore any prices on the website level.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't do it.
In the category view it still shows the global prices and after clicking on a product I get the website prices.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. If you change the global price scope, it should only use the global price. Have you re-indexed?

Comment: I never ever had the price scope not being global.
Should I try to change it to website, reindex, change it back to global, reindex? Doesn't sound reasonable to me!?

Comment: Maybe it is a wrong setting within Magemi, because this tool writes to the database directly. If so, it is out-of-scope. @Chris please check your import settings in Magemi